# DLE API в отдельном файле

Tags: dle

Как в dle получить информацию о авторизованном пользователе?
$member_id работает если подключать модуль через шаблон, а если обратиться к скрипту через site.com/action.php все в NULL.
Можно ли как то через api выполнять разного рода махинации непосредственно внутри отдельного файла?